# Conditional statement not working on a VueJs method

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, vuejs2, frontend

I'm trying to add conditional statement, so when the user toggle the buttons it would trigger an action, for example output the some text.

I tried to add the conditional as method, and as computed property without success, also I tried with switch statement.

I'll add the codepen link https://codepen.io/manosx/pen/KELmpj?editors=0010

```
  clickedTag: function (indexTag) {
      // toggle the active class
      this.$set(this.isClickedTag, indexTag, !this.isClickedTag[indexTag])
      let tagsSelected = _.keys(_.pickBy(this.isClickedTag, _.identity))
      let tagsSelectedSingle = tagsSelected.map(s => `'${s}'`).join(', ')
      console.log(tagsSelectedSingle)
      if (tagsSelectedSingle === '0') { console.log('naylon') }
      else if (tagsSelectedSingle === '1') { console.log('espiga') }
      else if (tagsSelectedSingle === '2') { console.log('omega') }
      else if (tagsSelectedSingle === '3') { console.log('crochet') }
      else if (tagsSelectedSingle === '4') { console.log('thread') }
      else if (tagsSelectedSingle === '5') { console.log('bordado') }
    },
```

I would like to add a conditional statement that would trigger different actions depending of the buttons that are on.

Comment: so, what you're asking is to put some other code instead of `console.log`? you can put anything inside those blocks, call any function you like ... so `mySuperSpecialFunction('naylon')` instead of `console.log('naylon')` - then all you need to do is create the `mySuperSpecialFunction` to do what you need it to do (which is vague in your question)

Comment: Not the If statement is not working, can't output anything of the console.log outputs

Comment: well, `tagsSelectedSingle = tagsSelected.map(s => `'${s}'`).join(', ')` suggests tagSelectedSingle isn't a single value at all - so, perhaps you need to keep it as an array, and use `tagSelectedSingle.includes('1')` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its beter to use `indexOf()`  because includes will not work on some browsers.

Try this.

```
if (tagsSelectedSingle.indexOf('0')>=0) { console.log('naylon') }
           if (tagsSelectedSingle.indexOf('1')>=0) { console.log('espiga') }
           if (tagsSelectedSingle.indexOf('2')>=0) { console.log('omega') }
           if (tagsSelectedSingle.indexOf('3')>=0) { console.log('crochet') }
           if (tagsSelectedSingle.indexOf('4')>=0) { console.log('thread') }
           if (tagsSelectedSingle.indexOf('5')>=0) { console.log('bordado') }
```

Comment: It works partially, for example when I turn on the first button it will output 'espiga', that result remains for all the subsequent buttons unless I deactivate the first button. I would like to output the result of each button independently for the rest of the actions on the buttons.